# Find a bar that intersects the biggest possible amount of points

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to find a solution for the following problem: Imagine you have a set of $n$ points, each defined by an $x$- and a $y$-coordinate. Now you need to find a bar with a specific width that intersects most of all points. 
Unfortunately I don't know how to describe / define such a bar.
[image]

In the picture you can see the green bar, which apparently intersects the biggest possible amount of points. So my question is how do you find this equation or something of the bar? 
I have already tried out the line of best fit. But there are scenarios, for example if the points are too far apart, that the "bar" of best fit didn't even touch one point. See second picture.[image]

Thank you!